# what the word ''cloth'' means after a ISBN number in a BOOK?

Tags: meaning

what the word ''cloth'' means after an ISBN number in a BOOK?

For example: ISBN-13:978-0-226-10420-1(cloth).

Comment: It means the book is bound in cloth, not as a 'paperback'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'general reference'.

Comment: Just to ensure that you understand the nomenclature used in bookbinding, "cloth" = "hardback."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this but I just did a search on the internet. Here are some websites I found.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookbinding

https://www.isbn-international.org/content/isbn-assignment

So it seems a new ISBN is given to each binding of a book, and this ISBN is attached to the cloth binding edition of the book.